# Commit failed while step execution data was already updated

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am getting Commit failed while step execution data was already updated error when spring batch try to commit the records. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am using HIbernate JPA .

It is working for lesser number of records. Throwing error when the record count is high.

Stack Trace:

```
2016-01-20 08:49:45 INFO  TaskletStep:359 - Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version.
2016-01-20 08:49:45 ERROR TaskletStep:370 - Rolling back with transaction in unknown state
2016-01-20 08:49:45 ERROR AbstractStep:225 - Encountered an error executing  step uploadFiles in job fileUploadJob
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException:  Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:524)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
```

Comment: Do you have some component marked with @Transactional? Usually it is the source of transaction problems

Comment: Thank you for reply. I dont have @Transactional anywhere in my code. It is working when i setted the commit interval to 1 .if i setted to 100 or 1000 or 10000 it is failing.

Answer (score 5):

I had same error "Commit failed while step execution data was already updated. Reverting to old version" and I solved it by using " @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)" annotation above the method where the records were committed.